# weird shell script error: invalid option return: usage: return [n]

Tags: shell, debugging, command-line

This programme checks if a certain book title exist by matching user input of book title and book author.

```
function removebook_option()
{
    echo -n "Title : "
    read title_input2

    echo -n "Author: "
    read author_input2

    checkexist $title_input2 $author_input2
    error=$? 
    echo "$error"

    if [ $error != -1 ];then
        #removebook
            echo "New book title $title_input removed successfully"
        else
        echo "Book does not exist"


    fi 

}

function checkexist()
{  
   counter=0

   for x in ${title[@]} 
   do

    for y in ${author[@]} 
    do
        if [  $x == $1 ] && [ $y == $2 ];
        then
            error=$counter 
                return "$error"
        fi
    done
    counter=$((counter+1))
   done

   error=-1
   return "$error"

}

title=(foo1 foo2)
author=(bar1 bar2)
removebook_option
```

I am getting a very weird error , where `function checkexist()` returns 2 instead of -1 when there isnt a match which happens when returning value `error=-1`

> line 43: return: -1: invalid option return: usage: return [n]

You can try to input incorrect data to see the weird error

**I need help resolving this issue thanks!!!!**

Comment: You cannot use `return` in shell functions. Maybe you can `echo` something and catch it when calling the function.

Comment: i am not sure about that, i saw code that uses return before , how do you echo code and catch it ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should return either 0 or positive integer between 1 and 255

according to http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html#FTN.AEN2974

> by convention, 0 on success or an integer in the range 1 - 255 on
>   error.

although you can use `return -- -1`
`$?` will show you 255 instead of -1

because -1 is out of the valid range

see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html#EXITCODESREF

> Out of range exit values can result in unexpected exit codes. An exit
>   value greater than 255 returns an exit code modulo 256. For example,
>   exit 3809 gives an exit code of 225 (3809 % 256 = 225).

Comment: is there anyway to return -1??

Comment: no, any number not between 0 and 255 will be changed to the valid range [0, 255]